# Rails: better way to check for associated object by name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following method in my Product model:

```
def has_feature? (feature_name)
  self.features.where(:name=>feature_name).present?
end
```

This seems to be very slow. Is there a better way of checking to see if my product has a feature with a given name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.present?` isn't a standard method on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` which is what `where` returns. Calling `.present?` is fetching all of the features with the given name, changing into an array and then calling `.present?` on the array.

If you call `.exists?` instead then the database query that is performed is slightly more optimised to checking whether that feature exists or not.

However, I'm not sure you'll notice much of a performance differences between the two options. The most likely cause is that you're missing a database index. Assuming that your association is `Product has_many :features` the database query that will get generated would be improved by an index on both `features.product_id` and `features.name`.

Comment: Would you suggest adding the indexes and calling .exists? or adding indexes and using scoping as suggested by Raghu

Comment: I would suggest adding an index with both fields and then from there using the approach that you feel most comfortable with.

Comment: Ok, I would be comfortable with either, I just meant .. what is best from a speed perspective... I'll assume from your response that it doesn't matter.

Comment: Sorry, I was implying, too subtly, that there won't be any appreciable difference between the two approaches after the index is added.

Comment: Not a problem. I have one more related question if you feel so inclined http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926627/adding-index-has-many-through-relationship

Answer (score 1):

One other way of writing this is using scope in your `Feature` model and see if it helps and do a `present?` on the resulting output of that scope

```
scope :includes_feature, lambda{ |feature|
  { :name => feature }
}
```

so finally what you can do is `product.features.includes_feature(feature_name)`