# Adding index in Rails has-many-through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

With the below relationship in mind:

```
class Style < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stylefeatures, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :features, :through => :stylefeatures
end

class Stylefeature < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :style
  belongs_to :feature
end

class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stylefeatures, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :styles, :through => :stylefeatures
end
```

How would I most efficiently add indexes to speed up this method in the Style model:

```
  def has_feature? (arg)
    self.features.where(:name=>arg).exists?
  end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class AddIndexesToStyleFeatures < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_index :stylefeatures , [:style_id , :feature_id] , :unique => true
    add_index :features , :name    # check your data before making this unique
  end

  def self.down
    drop_index :features , :name
    drop_index :stylefeatures, [:style_id , :feature_id]
  end
end
```

You might want to make the :name index on the :features class unique, but beware of this catch:

If you have records which can contain NULL / nil fields which are part of the index, 
then don't use unique indexes.  => check your data first

If during deletion of features it could happen that a StyleFeatures entry gets a nil reference (instead of being deleted altogether), then having a unique index will also cause problems for that table.

Make sure to double-check on how your particular database handles indexes when querying on null values.

See: [Rails uniqueness constraint and matching db unique index for null column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926763/rails-uniqueness-constraint-and-matching-db-unique-index-for-null-column)

and: [How to create a unique index on a NULL column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191421/how-to-create-a-unique-index-on-a-null-column)

Comment: see comment in my answer

Comment: As it turns out I already have this in my schema   add_index "stylefeatures", ["feature_id"], :name => "index_stylefeatures_on_feature_id"
  add_index "stylefeatures", ["style_id"], :name => "index_stylefeatures_on_style_id"

Comment: I will drop the index and re-add it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recomend adding a `unique` index on `stylefeatures style_id and feature_id` (as an array) and a `unique` index on `features.name`.

Comment: AS IN add_index :stylefeatures, [:style_id, :feature_id], :unique => true AND add_index :features, :name, :unique => true

Answer (score 1):

Small change to answer by **Tilo**: use `remove_index` instead of `drop_index`:

```
class AddIndexesToStyleFeatures < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_index :stylefeatures , [:style_id , :feature_id] , :unique => true
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index :stylefeatures, [:style_id , :feature_id]
  end
end
```